# Event handler on parent catches event from child

Tags: c#, wpf, events

Probably I have not really understood the event system in WPF.

I have a TabItem that has a header consisting of a TextBox and a Button. The TextBox is readonly. (*In the real application it allows editing on double clicking, but that's irrelevant here.*)

It was difficult to select a tab because the TextBox grabs the MouseLeftButtonDown event. I therefore added an event handler to the TabItem that brings it into foreground. However with that event handler the button no longer receives the event. Why does the button not get the event before the TabItem gets the event? I thought it bubbles from the leaves to the root of the logical tree.

Here's the XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="tt_WPF.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:tt_WPF"
    Title="MainWindow" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
<TabControl x:Name="TC"></TabControl> 
</Window>
```

Here's the code behind:

```
   public class myItem : TabItem
{
    public myItem(string name)
    {
        // Create horizontal StackPanel
        StackPanel sp = new StackPanel();
        sp.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
        // Create a readonly TextBox
        TextBox tb = new TextBox(); 
        tb.Text = name;
        tb.IsReadOnly = true;
        // Create a Button with a simple command
        Button b = new Button();
        b.Content = "X";
        b.Click += Button_Click;
        // Add Button and TextBlock to StackPanel and StackPanel to this TabIten
        sp.Children.Add(tb);
        sp.Children.Add(b);
        this.Header = sp;
        this.Content = "This is " + name;
        // --> Here's the trouble: Install an event handler that brings the TabItem into foreground when clicked
        this.AddHandler(MouseLeftButtonDownEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(TabItem_MouseLeftButtonDownEvent), true);

    }
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Button X");
    }
    private void TabItem_MouseLeftButtonDownEvent(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.IsSelected = true;
    }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        TC.Items.Add(new myItem("Tab 1"));
        TC.Items.Add(new myItem("Tab 2"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The thing you have faced is called [event routing in WPF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806(v=vs.110).aspx). To prevent event from being routed to the next level you have to set `Handled = true`. Also you can check for sender type which raised this event to filter out unnecessary calls.

```
private void TabItem_MouseLeftButtonDownEvent(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.IsSelected = true;
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

There is a very nice diagram displaying events routing when it comes to user input ([from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806(v=vs.110).aspx#how_event_processing_works)):

[image: Events routing]

So to get desired *bottom->up* routing path you need to change behavior to `Bubble` instead of `Tunnel` by using `PreviewLeftMouseButtonDown`.

Comment: It doesn't make a difference when I put `e.Handled = true` into `TabItem_MouseLeftButtonDownEvent()`;
 
I would expect the event to be first occur at the button and then at the containing TabItem.

Comment: Thanks Anatolii, changing the event to the preview type did it. (_I have a text book that says MouseLeftButtonDown would be of type Bubble, which is wrong as it seems; it also mentions that MSDN show the strategy to be direct_).

**I'm still puzzled though**. Assuming that MouseLeftButtonDown is tunneling: When I set the third parameter to AddHandler (HandledEventsToo) to false, the event handler is no longer called but the button receives the event. That would make sense to me only if this would be a bubbling event.

Comment: Also: If it would be tunneling setting e.Handled to false should instruct the event to travel further down the tree. But that does not happen either.

Comment: I have a strong feeling that issues you're facing related to the fact that you create conrtols on code-behind (_will check and confirm_). Try xaml instead.

Comment: My real program is really in XAML. I put it in code to have it more coherent for posting. Error is exactly the same. Did you by any chance check out the code in VS?

Comment: No. It has nothing to do with that. Creating things in XAML shows the same behavior. I seems it has to do with the fact the setting `isSelected = true;´ messes up the event sequence.